# CSS borders issue on MS Edge

Tags: css, tabs, border

I am trying to implement this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp
except with additional borders.

When I select Tokyo, or mouse out of Paris, the menu button side borders disappear using MS Edge. It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Tabs by Aubrey Bourke 2019 -->

<head>
<style>

body{
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
}
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;

  background-color: #f1f1f1;

}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;

}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  /*background-color: #ddd;*/

}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: white;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  background-color: white;
}


.container{
box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px 0px #eee;
width: 500px;
}
#blank{
background-color:#efefef;
cursor: default;
}
#one{
background-color:white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="openCity(event, 'London')">


<div class="container">

<div class="tab">
  <button id="one" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button id="two" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button id="three" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
  <button id="blank" class="tablinks" style="width:255px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">&nbsp;</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");


  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

 if(cityName=="London"){    

    <!-- One -->
    document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor="white";
    document.getElementById("one").style.borderRight="1px solid #ccc";
    document.getElementById("one").style.borderBottom="1px solid white";

    <!-- Two -->
        document.getElementById("two").style.borderLeft="0px solid #ccc";
    document.getElementById("two").style.borderRight="0px solid #ccc";

    document.getElementById("two").style.borderBottom="1px solid #ccc";


    <!-- Three -->
        document.getElementById("three").style.borderLeft="1px solid #efefef";
    document.getElementById("three").style.borderRight="1px solid #efefef";
    document.getElementById("three").style.borderBottom="1px solid #ccc";

}


 if(cityName=="Paris"){


    <!-- One -->
    document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor="#f1f1f1";
    document.getElementById("one").style.borderRight="1px solid #ccc";
    document.getElementById("one").style.borderBottom="1px solid #ccc";


    <!-- Two -->
        document.getElementById("two").style.borderLeft="1px solid #efefef";
    document.getElementById("two").style.borderRight="1px solid #ccc";
    document.getElementById("two").style.borderBottom="1px solid white";


    <!-- Three -->
        document.getElementById("three").style.borderLeft="1px solid #efefef";
    document.getElementById("three").style.borderRight="1px solid #efefef";
    document.getElementById("three").style.borderBottom="1px solid #ccc";


}
if(cityName=="Tokyo"){

    <!-- One -->
    document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor="#f1f1f1";
    document.getElementById("one").style.borderRight="1px solid #efefef";
    document.getElementById("one").style.borderBottom="1px solid #ccc";


    <!-- Two -->
        document.getElementById("two").style.borderLeft="1px solid #efefef";
    document.getElementById("two").style.borderRight="1px solid #ccc";
    document.getElementById("two").style.borderBottom="1px solid #ccc";

    <!-- Three -->
        document.getElementById("three").style.borderLeft="1px solid #efefef";
    document.getElementById("three").style.borderRight="1px solid #ccc";
    document.getElementById("three").style.borderBottom="1px solid white";

}


}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me why the borders disappear after hovering over them in MS Edge? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Not an answer, but may I ask why you're applying these borders with JavaScript? It feels like you could accomplish things much more simply with CSS. Looking into your issue, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not quite an answer to your question, but rather a different approach that works in classic Edge and other modern browsers.

I think there are better strategies for marking up and styling these tabs, but I stuck *generally* with the markup you provided. May not be at all what you're looking for, but perhaps it may be somewhat helpful in thinking through the relevant issues (e.g., extracting styling from JS, etc.).

I've leaned on CSS to do the heavy lifting with regard to styling and tried to simplify the JavaScript so that it does what it does well. I typically shy far away from adding styles to elements via JS unless I have a specific use case that constrains me to do so. That's generally good practice, but perhaps you have reasons I don't know for doing it like you did.

Best of luck.

```js
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
      var i, tabcontent;
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      var toggleTabs = function (e) {
        var active = document.querySelector('.active');
        if (active) {
          active.classList.remove('active');
        }
        e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
      }
      var tablinks = document.querySelectorAll(".tablinks");
      var tablinksSet = Array.from(tablinks);
      tablinksSet.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          toggleTabs(e);
        })
      })
    }
```

```css
 body {
      font-family: Sans-serif;
      background-color: white;
    }

    /* Style the tab */
    .tab {
      position: relative;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-color: #ccc #ccc transparent #ccc;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
    .tab button {
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      margin-top: -1px;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 16px 16px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      font-size: 17px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc;

    }

    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
    .tab button:hover {
      /*background-color: #ddd;*/

    }

    /* Create an active/current tablink class */
    .tab button.active {
      position: relative;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-bottom-color: white;
    }

    .tab button.active::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      bottom: -2px;
      left: 0;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 50;
    }

    .tab button:first-child {
      margin-left: -1px;
    }

    .tab button:not(.active):first-child {
      border-left-color: #ccc;
    }

    .tabcontents {
      width: 500px;
      float: left;
    }

    /* Style the tab content */
    .tabcontent {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      display: none;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      margin-top: -1px;
      background-color: white;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-color: #ccc #ccc #ccc #ccc;
    }

    .cf:before,
    .cf:after {
      content: " ";
      display: table;
    }

    .cf:after {
      clear: both;
    }

    .container {
      width: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body onload="openCity(event, 'London')">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tab cf">
      <button id="one" class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
      <button id="two" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
      <button id="three" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tabcontents">
      <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>London</h3>
        <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Paris</h3>
        <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Tokyo</h3>
        <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's really really awesome. Thanks for taking the time to help me.